# Why the DNS query retransmission sent from the KVM machine with bridge network

Tags: domain-name-system

I am using this command to test DNS resolve in my KVM machine(`ip:192.168.31.30`),and using bridge network with the host machine(`br0: 192.168.31.2`) :

```
    [root@k8sslave1 var]# dig www.ifeng.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.13-RedHat-9.11.13-3.el8 <<>> www.ifeng.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I am tracing the network traffic on my host machine using Wireshark, this is the filter:

```
ip.dst == 8.8.8.8 && ip.proto == 17 && dns.qry.name == "www.ifeng.com"
```

and the result shows DNS query retransmission, so why the DNS query retransmission? when I ping from host `192.168.31.2` to `192.168.31.30` it works fine.

```
[dolphin@localhost infrastructure]$ ping 192.168.31.30
PING 192.168.31.30 (192.168.31.30) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.31.30: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.175 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.31.30: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.201 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.31.30: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.388 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.31.30: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.349 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.31.30: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.383 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.31.30: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.236 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.31.30: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.243 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.31.30: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.370 ms
```

this is Wireshark output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One cause of this can be that the firewall is not set up to forward the replies from the public interface to the bridge.  Try `iptables-save | grep FORWARD` to see what is being forwarded.

Depending on what is there currently, you might need to add something like:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

It looks like you may be using NAT (given the 192.168.x.x addressing) so you could also need entries in your NAT table.  Because DNS generally uses UDP which is stateless, the return route needs to be explicitly allowed.

Try adding `+tcp` to the `dig` command to see if the connection works over TCP; if so, this would give further evidence that it is a firewall issue.

Showing your existing firewall rules on the host would be useful.